# Why is the value of vif from $(X'X)^{-1}$ not matching the result?

Tags: multiple-regression, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

The diagonal elements of matrix $C = (X'X)^{-1}$ are
$C_{jj} = \frac{1}{1-R_{j}^{2}}$  (which is nothing but the vif) of $x_j$ where $j = 1, 2, 3, ..., n$ and $X$ is a $n\times p$ matrix and $R_j^2$ is the is the coefficient of multiple determination resulting from regressing $x_j$ on the other variables.
I was trying to verify the above result using some example.
Consider

> $X = \begin{matrix}
>   2 & 19 \\
>   3 & 18 \\
>    4 & 17 \\
>  5 & 16 \\
>  6 &20\\
>  8 & 25\\
>  7& 31\\
>  4 & 15\\
>  3 & 18\\
>  2 & 11
>  \end{matrix}$

Now I regress the first column on the second column and get $R_1^2 = 0.5594$.
Therefore VIF of $1st$ column is $\frac{1}{1-0.5594^2} = 2.269756$.
But the matrix

> $C = \begin{matrix}
> 0.057 & -0.013\\
> -0.013 & 0.003\\
> \end{matrix}$

Why are the diagonal entries not equal to the VIF. What's wrong?

Comment: You answered your own question: the diagonal elements of C are not the VIFs.

Comment: Your question changes the meaning of "$X$" and thereby does not carry out the calculations you describe.  When you regressed the first column on the second, your design matrix $X$ (in the sense of the first line of your post, not in the sense of your data!) was merely the second column (plus a column of constants), whereas your $C$ is the correlation matrix of the two columns.  Because that involves data (namely, the first column) that were not included in the design matrix of the regression, then *of course* there is no relationship among the results.